# Leanft handling waits

Tags: leanft

Are there other waits besides leanft.exists() and the following below. I'm back g to wait a lot to determine if something is clickable

[Leanft waits](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.01/NetSDKReference/HP.LFT.SDK~HP.LFT.SDK.TestObjectExtensions~WaitUntil.html)

My application is a Single Page Javascript application using ReactJS. The challenge is that sometimes the selenium click does not work. It executes the line, but I was not navigated to the next route or page. In addition, it does not throw an exception until you execute the next line expecting to be on the new page. I would have to perform the click again. In essence, I need a way to pass a condition to a click method to verify that if I click on some element I expect to see some other element. If the click does not happen return false and click again. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you linked towards C# sdk, so I'll answer in C#.

`WaitUntil` executes the provided boolean method until it returns `true`. So if you implement your own method:

```
 private bool funcToRun(IBrowser arg)
 {
     // imeplement whatever logic you want here
     return true;
 }
```

Then you can call `WaitUntil` as follows: `browser.WaitUntil(funcToRun);`

Of course make sure that your `funcToRun` takes as argument the correct test object (the one on which you'll actually call `.WaitUntil`).

As you'll have access to the test object in the `funcToRun` method, you can wait until any logic you want.
Here's [another example](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/CodeSamples_.NET/CodeEx.NETJava.htm#hp-minitoc-item-1) using arrow functions, that doesn't wait for a button to `.Exist()`, but for the `Buttons` array to have `16` elements.:

```
// Create a description for the Toolbar.
var toolBar = window.Describe<IToolBar>(new ToolBarDescription
{
    NativeClass = "SwingSet2$ToggleButtonToolBar"
});

// There are 16 buttons in the toolbar. Use the WaitUntil method to wait until all 16 buttons are loaded.
// This ensures that any button we press was loaded. If not loaded, the test fails.
toolBar.WaitUntil(tb => (tb.Buttons.Count == 16));
```

Comment: How can i pass a condition to the click.  For example, sometimes I perform the click and the click does not happen. How do I handle that. I want to perform something like click until you see something.

Comment: I posed the followup question above

Comment: That depends on how your AUT works - I can't answer until you give me more details and are more specific

Comment: My application is a Single Page Javascript application using ReactJS.  The challenge is that sometimes the selenium click does not work.  It executes the line, but I was not navigated to the next route or page.  In addition, it does not throw an exception until you execute the next line expecting to be on the new page.  I would have to perform the click again.  In essence, I need a way to pass a condition to a click method to verify that if I click on some element I expect to see some other element.  If the click does not happen return false and click again. Does that make sense?